# BizTalk 2013 R2 - Orchestration Debugging Server Side

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2, bhm

I am trying to debug an orchestration inside BizTalk 2013 R2 server using BizTalk Health Monitor.

In past versions, you could just right click on the orchestration and select debugging.

Seems like that functionality is no longer available.

**My BHM**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should go to BizTalk Admin Console and stop the orchestration and once a instance is suspended then resume it with debugger. BHM does not provide orchestration debugging functionality.

Answer (score 1):

BizTalk Health Monitor only shows you the current shape for certain Orchestrations, not full debugging off the Orchestration.

[BizTalk Health Monitor v3.1 released!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/biztalkhealthmonitor/archive/2015/07/02/biztalk-health-monitor-v3-1-released.aspx)

> Added View Current Shape of Orchestrations to BHM report
>
> We have included a script which provides a way to quickly see which shape orchestrations are on without relying on tracking or orchestration debugger. This task relies on the nvcLastAction column in the Instances table which is only available starting BTS2006R2 and is only populated for orchestrations that are either dehydrated, active but dehydratable, or were suspended while dehydratable.  If a certain orchestration does not show up in this list, it does not have any nvcLastAction info associated with it.